# Create dialog when there is an empty field

Tags: java, android, dialog, alert

I've been struggling with this problem, that keep crashing my app every time there is an empty field in it.

when I run the code, it tells me that there is an error in the lines 32 and 37, right where I transform the string from the textView to integers to do the operations with those numbers

[image: Error Image]

It'd be great if you guys could check this out.

```
package com.studium.second.secondtest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Activity miActividad;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        miActividad = this;


        Button calcular = findViewById(R.id.button1);

        calcular.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                TextView textoBase = findViewById(R.id.areaBase);
                String base = textoBase.getText().toString();
                int numeroBase = Integer.parseInt(base);


                TextView textoAltura = findViewById(R.id.areaAltura);
                String altura = textoAltura.getText().toString();
                int numeroAltura = Integer.parseInt(altura);

                //Operación
                final TextView cajaResultado = findViewById(R.id.areaResultado);

                final int operacion = numeroAltura * numeroBase;
                cajaResultado.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.textoResultado ) + " " + operacion);

                if (base == null && altura != null){
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(miActividad.getApplicationContext());
                    builder.setMessage("El parámetro base está vacío")
                            .setCancelable(false)
                            .setNegativeButton("Volver", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            });
                    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                    alert.show();
                }

                if (base != null && altura == null){
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(miActividad.getApplicationContext());
                    builder.setMessage("El parámetro altura está vacío")
                            .setCancelable(false)
                            .setNegativeButton("Volver", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            });
                    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                    alert.show();
                }


                if (base == null && altura == null){
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(miActividad.getApplicationContext());
                    builder.setMessage("Todos los parámetros están vacíos")
                            .setCancelable(false)
                            .setNegativeButton("Volver", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            });
                    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                    alert.show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: your `String` is empty thats why

Comment: initialize your string first then check if(base.gettext()!=""){...}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String base = textoBase.getText().toString();
int numeroBase = Integer.parseInt(base);

String altura = textoAltura.getText().toString();
int numeroAltura = Integer.parseInt(altura);
```

You can't perform `.parseInt` on an empty String. This will of course result in a crash. You have to check for an empty String before.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

Before this line `int numeroBase = Integer.parseInt(base);` Write this:

```
if (base.contentEquals("")) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please enter a value in Base", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show;
else {
    int numeroBase = Integer.parseInt(base);
    ....
}
```

and do the same for this line too: `int numeroAltura = Integer.parseInt(altura);`

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Write a null check on the String that you getting as input and after that perform parsing.

In your case do it like this :

```
            TextView textoBase = findViewById(R.id.areaBase);
            String base = textoBase.getText().toString().trim();
            if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(base))
               int numeroBase = Integer.parseInt(base);
            else 
              // Show some message like "Field is Mandatory"

            TextView textoAltura = findViewById(R.id.areaAltura);
            String altura = textoAltura.getText().toString().trim();
            if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(base))
               int numeroAltura = Integer.parseInt(altura);
            else 
              // Show some message like "Field is Mandatory"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
```